# How to rewrite URL to another folder using Firebase?

Tags: url, web, firebase, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

I would like to rewrite URL for example `myweb.com/index` and show content of `myweb.com/production/index.com` and I want to do that for all pages, that they would be showing content of the same file but in the directory `production`.
I mean, that `Firebase.json` would look something like this (of course this doesn't work):

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public",
        "cleanUrls": true,
        "rewrites": [ {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/production/**"
        }
        ]


    }
}
```